# A Short Proof that the Center of a Frobenius Kernel is non-trivial

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

I am aware of Thompson's result that a Frobenius kernel is nilpotent.  Is there a short proof that a Frobeneius kernel has a nontrivial center?

Comment: What is a frobenius kernel

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_group